# R Programming/ Shiny/ Reading values from table

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm new to programming and I am trying to learn R Programming.

I  made a table in R using the rhandsontable library.

I would like to know if it's possible to read values from a user in the table generated by rhandsontable and process the values provided by the user?

Kindly provide some examples
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you already seen a handful set of [these examples](http://rpubs.com/jrowen/intro_rhandsontable)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really helpful.